# PHP creates my serverside jpg file not sends it

Tags: php, email

My Canvas image saves correctly however i need to get it to then email itself to a preset email, my PHP skills have gotten me this far however everything else i have been trying has failed.

this is my working code.

```
<?

// set error reporting level
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=') == 1)
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
else
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// save file
if ($_POST['data'] != '') {

$sRand = rand(100000, 999999);
$sOrigPath = 'cache/result'.$sRand.'.jpg';
@unlink($sOrigPath);

$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = strip_tags($img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$decodedData = base64_decode($img);

file_put_contents($sOrigPath, $decodedData);
echo $sOrigPath;
```

``}

This works perfectly however i know im missing something so simple however i cannot get it to email. if anyone could help then that would be amazing.

Thanks guys for your help. I managed it in the end however i did it using this code with a few customizations. http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/mail2.htm i hope this helps someone with similar issues.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you remove HTML tags from a picture?

Comment: Do you have a question? Your script will not send an e-mail message for the same reason that it won't generate a PDF file or decode human DNA: you haven't written code to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the email, with the image inside the email. Emails do accept HTML if the correct headers are set. See the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function for reference.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail("someemail@google.com", "Some subject", "<img src='path/to/your/saved/image.jpg'/>", $headers);
```

For this to work, you have to have a SMTP server installed. If on linux, you can easily install `postfix`, which runs out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this sends an email however its not the image. any suggestions?

Comment: Does anything show in the body of the email? Also, please double check that the path of the image in the `img` tag is correct and please try to include the full URL (including the hostname). 2 things are needed for image displays in emails: text/html in the headers and the `img` tag, which I've both included in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'mail' function in php
In the 'message' field put

```
$msg = "<img src='". $sOrigPath."'>";
```

Comment: sorry again its not sending the image correctly, however it does try but still no good :(

Comment: Have you send a mail whitout an image? May the mail service is not well configurated.
Or another thing can be the route, verify if you are using a relative route